# Parameterization of a curve to compute a line integral

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, curves

I am solving line integrals of vectorial functions and, when the curve along it is defined the integral is given by its parameterization, I have no problem in solving it. However, I am stuck in examples like the following when I need to obtain a parameterization.

The curve is $C=\{(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2|x=y^2,y=x^2,0\leq x\leq 1, 0 \leq y \leq 1\}$. Obviously it doesn't work fixing $x=t$ for example. The function to integrate along $C$ is, by the way, $F(x,y)=(2x+y^2,3y-4x)$
Appreciate any kind of help. Thank you.

Comment: I think you are expected to use Green's theorem as the curve is closed.

Comment: Are there one or two curves here? If it's intended as two, then it's going to be both clearer and more useful define them separately as $C_1,C_2$.

Comment: The set $C$ you defined contains only two points $(0,0)$ and $(1,1)$.

Comment: Sure @Semiclassical I haven't thought of dividing it in two curves easily parameterizable.

Comment: In that case you can just do $\int_C=\int_{C_1}+\int_{C_2}$ and the calculation should go easily.